# Paint Method in an Applet (Sort Algorithms in Java)

Tags: java, swing, sorting, applet, paint

I have two classes: One applet for the GUI and one class to sort numbers.

Sort Class:

```
public class Sortierung {

public int[] Zahlen = {5,2,3,1,4};
int z;



public static int zufallszahl (int z){
 int dauer = ((int)(Math.random()*z))+1;
 return dauer;
}

   public void ArrayErstellen(int l){
    int[] myIntArray = new int[l];
  for(int f=0;f<myIntArray.length;f++){
      myIntArray[f]=zufallszahl(10);
    }
    Zahlen=myIntArray;
}

public int[] BubbleSort() {
  for(int p=0;p<Zahlen.length-1;p++){
   for(int i=0;i<Zahlen.length-1;i++){
     if(Zahlen[i]<Zahlen[i+1]){
       continue;  //beendet den derzeitigen Schleifenablauf
     }
     else{
      z=Zahlen[i];
      Zahlen[i]=Zahlen[i+1];
      Zahlen[i+1]=z;

     }
   }
  }
  return Zahlen;
}

public int[] InsertionSort() {
 int f = 0; //Variable 1
 int j = 0; //Variable 2
  for(int i = 1;i < Zahlen.length;i++){ 
   j = i; 
    while((j>0)&&(Zahlen[j-1]>Zahlen[j])){
     f = Zahlen[j-1];
     Zahlen[j-1] = Zahlen[j];
     Zahlen[j] = f;
     j--;
    }
   }
  return Zahlen;
}

public int[] SelectionSort(){

    for (int i = 0; i < Zahlen.length - 1; i++){
        int s = i; //Neue Variable für die Schleife
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Zahlen.length; j++)
            if (Zahlen[j] < Zahlen[s]){    
                s = j;
            }    

        int smallerNumber = Zahlen[s];  
        Zahlen[s] =Zahlen[i];
        Zahlen[i] = smallerNumber;
    }
    return Zahlen;
}

public void ArrayWiedergeben(int[] eimer){
  for(int u=0;u<eimer.length;u++){
    System.out.println(eimer[u]);
  }
}  }
```

Gui (Applet):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Gui extends JApplet {

    JTextField tf;
    JButton b;
    JButton k;
    JLabel s;
    JLabel u;
    int anzahl;
    int test = 0;

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel h = new JPanel();
    JPanel f = new JPanel();
    Sortierung neu = new Sortierung();
    Choice Sortierungsmethode = new Choice();

    ActionListener startOhr = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            anzahl = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
            if (anzahl > 100) {
                tf.setText("Wert zu hoch.");
                return;
            }
            neu.ArrayErstellen(anzahl);
            tf.setText("Array[" + anzahl + "] erstellt.");
        }
    };

    ActionListener sortOhr = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (Sortierungsmethode.getSelectedIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    int[] eimer = neu.BubbleSort();
                    neu.ArrayWiedergeben(eimer);
                    test = 1;
                    repaint();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    int[] eimer2 = neu.InsertionSort();
                    neu.ArrayWiedergeben(eimer2);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    int[] eimer3 = neu.SelectionSort();
                    neu.ArrayWiedergeben(eimer3);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void init() {
        tf = new JTextField(8);
        b = new JButton("Erstellen");
        k = new JButton("Bestätigen");
        s = new JLabel("Array Länge");
        u = new JLabel("Sortmethode");
        Sortierungsmethode.add("Bubblesort");
        Sortierungsmethode.add("Insertionsort");
        Sortierungsmethode.add("Selectionsort");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(s);
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(b);
        h.add(u);
        h.add(Sortierungsmethode);
        h.add(k);

        this.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(h, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(f, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        b.addActionListener(startOhr);
        k.addActionListener(sortOhr);
    }
}
```

My intention is to draw the sorted array in a coordinate system with a paint 
method. The problem is, that when I try to create a paint method, the whole screen is white and I cant see anything

Comment: Please show your attempt at a `paint()` method.

Comment: Even If I create an empty paint method: public void paint (Graphics g){} the screen gets white :(

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Of course an empty `paint()` method doesn't paint anything.

Comment: Without the paint method it looks like that (correct): http://prntscr.com/iggfjk, but with the paint method like this: http://prntscr.com/iggfu3

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Don't mix Swing & AWT components. 4) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Answer (score 1):

You need to address several details:

1. You should create a class which overrides `JPanel` to do your custom drawing. You can create an instance of the class in your `Gui` class.
2. You should override `paintComponet()` rather than `paint()`.
3. The first line in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` should be `super.paintComponent(g)` in order to ensure that the super class can paint itself.
4. You need to be careful that your sorting algorithm doesn't take over the main thread. This will cause your app to freeze and nothing will paint until the sorting has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Thread` object and set it to call `run` method 30 times per second. In this method, call `repaint()` method of main `JPanel`.